# IntelliJ is using unexpected source directory from annotation processing output

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a  Gradle project that has some annotation processing involved (this time Mapstruct)

If I don't have any additional source directories IntelliJ is generating the classes in `src/main/generated`

As soon as I add an additional source directory e.g.

`sourceSets.main.java.srcDir { "${project.buildDir}/generated-src/1" }`

then IntelliJ starts to generate the annotation processor classes in that directory `build/generated-src/1`. Interestingly if I have additional source locations it takes the first one alphabetically.

**Note that I'm using the *Build and run using IntelliJ IDEA* build option under Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Toosl > Gradle**

Example project is available here: https://github.com/tkgregory/gradle-src-directory-issue.git

Is this the expected behaviour? When combinging Jooq + Mapstruct I'm getting Mapstruct classes generated under a source directory added by the Jooq plugin.

Comment: Why is it unexpected? Are there any problems with the project?

Comment: Let's say I have a plugin that creates it's own source set for itself, then IntelliJ will start to generate annotation processor classes into that directory for a completely unrelated annotation processor. This can be confusing.

The other behaviour I've been seeing is a duplicate class error between annotation processor generated classes generated by Gradle and those generated by IntelliJ.

Comment: @Andrey Additionally, since the generated directory is in `src` and not in `build`, they are not put in a proper location for build artifacts.  By extension, when using get, standard `.gitignore` rules would fail to ignore them since they are generated in a location that shouldn't normally be ignored.